# Angular 8 Angular Element (Custom web component) styling

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, element

I have a problem with my custom angular element.
I would like to override my whole components styling, by css file.
I am also using bootstrap in my project, which is imported in my parent component like this:

```
styleUrls: ['./chat-parent-component.component.scss', '../../../styles/bootstrap.min.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

this seems to work fine, but I have a problem with bootstrap now. It is also propagated to the whole page (not only to my widget), I guess it's because encapsulation set to 'None'. The problem is, if I remove this ViewEncapsulation, I'm not able to override any styles on my widget (custom element) and my styles are broken (no bootstrap at all).

This is how I'm overriding all elements in my external css file:
ex.

```
body .chat-button-popup-revealed {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00000029;
}
```

Do you know, how am I suppose to style and close this style only in angular element? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try in component .css file this `::ng-deep .chat-button-popup-revealed {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00000029;
}`?

Comment: yes, but it's not working :<

Comment: If I removed: encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, my app does not see bootstrap at all. I have also tried to add this to angular.json into styles, but it seems to not work anyway.

Comment: My problem is, how can I encapsulate bootstrap classes, to be seen only in my widget, instead of the whole page. I would like to place my widget in different sites, to not involve in any site bootstrap files. I would like it to be seen only in my widget.